# Heroku server restart command throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, server, rubygems, spree

When I am trying to restart the heroku server using the command `heroku restart --app skinnymint-staging`

Its giving error as follows:

```
lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2159:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x3fd6490129e4 heroku-3.42.15> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/Topform/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
from /Users/Topform/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
from /Users/Topform/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@skinnymint/gems/heroku-3.42.15/bin/heroku:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Topform/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@skinnymint/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
from /Users/Topform/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@skinnymint/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/Topform/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@skinnymint/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/Topform/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@skinnymint/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Please help me to get rid of the above error and execute the command successfully?

Comment: The command do not starts the server. It is not executed successfully. It gives the above error. Can you help me getting rid of the error?

Comment: What version of RoR, you are using?

Comment: ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-darwin14.0],
Rails 4.1.7

Comment: Looks like a bug - I've created an issue at https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1905 to track.

Comment: Thanks john ! lets see when this is going to get resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by running the command;

`heroku update`

The solution was provided by the Heroku technical team after I raised a ticket over there.